# Qt GUI non responsive on Windows XP

Tags: multithreading, qt, portability

I have a Qt application which gets serial data and displays is in a dashboard type GUI. The basic structure of the program is as follows:

**EDIT**
SerialPort (Inherits from QIODevice) object get created and have their readyRead signals connected to a slot. 
When new data comes in, it's interpreted and sent through the program via a message handler. Eventually the data makes its way to a GUI layer, where it is displayed to the user.

The program runs fine in windows 7, however when I run it on a Panasonic toughbook, running windows XP, the program starts off fine, but after a few moments the GUI stops updating. What I mean by this is that when new data comes in, the gui won't redraw until a user clicks a button or resizes. I'm wondering what are some possible reasons for this type of behavior. I thought it could be that the Main thread was getting overwhelmed by all the serial data coming in, but I think that the GUI runs in a separate thread anyways. Am I wrong? Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be happening?

Comment: Not sure.  Symptoms of GUI-thread input queue overload are usually that clicks/resizes/moves stop working, rather than making the app work.

Answer (score 0):

If `SerialPortIO` isn't in its own thread, then it might be blocking when it is waiting for new data.  I haven't used that particular Serial class, but in general a stream of data probably should be in its own thread.

You can force the program to update the GUI more, by calling `qApp->processEvents()` periodically, and the GUI should update.

Also, put some `qDebug` statements in your code, especially at the top of your functions that you suspect that are getting called too frequently or not enough.

Use the following line, and it makes it really easy to follow what is happening in a multithreaded application:

```
qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry the class is called SerialPort - It inherits from QIODevice..I'll make those changes, and I will try your suggestion